# NSNotificationCenter and didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have some problems with NSNotificationCenter and didReceiveRemoteNotification. I want to open my ViewController when i receive new notification from APNS. Inside body notification i have objectId - it's key.
I try to open my ViewController into didReceiveRemoteNotification but it's not working ((

AppDelegate.m

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{   
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:kDidReceiveRemoteNotification
 object:userInfo];
}
```

NewsDetailViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(didReceiveRemoteNotification:)
 name:kDidReceiveRemoteNotification
 object:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSLog(@"%s %@",__func__,[notification.userInfo description]);
 }
```

Const.h

```
#define kDidReceiveRemoteNotification @"UIApplicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification"
```

ViewController not loaded. i dont know what to do.

Comment: NSNotificationCenter has got nothing to do with remote notifications. I suggest you read about it and about push notification as you seem to be mixing them up? If you want to open your view controller then you could just do so directly within didRecevieRemoteNotification. I don't know why you are mentioning the objectId key, you are not using it anywhere, nor do you say how you intend to use it or what it is for.

Comment: @MartinH i try open view controller without NSNotificationCenter. My view controller open but not loaded - empty space, but must be loaded WebView or not loaded Navigation Bar ((( I dont know want to do((

Comment: You seem to be expecting NSNotificationCenter to open the view controller for you, I have no idea where you could have got that idea from. "i try open view controller without NSNotificationCenter." I think you should start a new question showing how you tried to open the view controller and start from there.

Comment: @MartinH I just think people will show the sample code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current flow of the sample code you've attached is:

1. When receiving push notification, post a notification to NSNotificationCenter (something completely different and unrelated to push notifications).
2. When another view is loaded (someone needed to load this view before the push notification was received), subscribe to this NSNotificationCenter notification.
3. When the notification is posted, print it to log.

It was hard for me to understand this from your question, but if the view controller you're trying to launch as a result of receiving the push notification is NewsDetailViewController, then your code doesn't do that. What you're code does is prints out the notification to log (assuming that somebody else made sure that NewsDetailViewController is loaded before the push notification was received).

In order to load the NewsDetailViewController when the push notification is received, you don't need to post the notification to NSNotification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{   
    NewsDetailViewController *newsVC = [[NewsDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:newsVC.view];
}
```

Or any other loading logic that works better for you. But in the current code you posted, there is no connection between receiving the push notification and loading the ViewController.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: thanx for a help, but variable self.view - AppDelegate not see, maybe     self.window.rootViewController?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was writing this as if it was in a UIViewController and not in AppDelegate. I edited the post with a fix.

Comment: @Chouch hm my app is crash. "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle" maybe app not see view controller.

Comment: You need to have a .xib file with the matching name, change the name in the code snippet to the name in your project, or just load the view without a nib. Change the loading method to whichever one you see fit, but the main idea is that you don't need to use NSNotificationCenter

Comment: @Choch thanx it's good idea. Last question - when i load my view from appdelegate my navigationbar (with buttons and etc) not showing, body with text in WebView and toolbar is showing and working, but navigationbar not showing, what is it?

Comment: When working with a navigation bar, you should be working with a navigation controller for pushing/popping view controllers and not adding them directly like I wrote in my original answer. Once you do it like that, it will probably resolve your issue.

Comment: But then I made a navigation bar is loaded, but the body and toolbar not loading ((just an empty space. I dont know what to do, maybe write function for loading webview and toolbar and using when i create object view controller.

Comment: You should post your code as a separate question so that it'd be easier to help you